# Angular2 RC.1 Router: Loading Routes Asynchronously

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm currently attempting to move my ng2 project from beta to release candidate 1. Everything is going well apart from upgrading to the new router.

My project is quite extensive and I've made good use of the `AsyncRoute` module in the now deprecated beta version of the router.

It appears that the new router does not have this functionality which means that on every load, every component is requested through SystemJS which obviously doesn't make much sense to do.

The docs don't make any mention of how to implement this form of Async loading, and I'm yet to find any good documentation on how to migrate to the new router.

Is there a way that I can implement Async loading of routes so that component files are requested only when required? If there isn't, then migrating to webpack in place of SystemJS seems like a better and faster option for module loading.

Comment: I haven't tried async loading in the old router but from what I have read about the new router now every route is async. There are still several issues in the new router so don't be suprised if you run into one ;-)

Comment: Issues? Geez - the last few days has been difficult! Introduce a totally new and problematic module into an RC? I'd be suggesting to anyone who is developing ng2 apps atm to hold off on this rc.